# Is there a way to set a heroku app as private?

Tags: heroku, configuration

Is there a way to set a heroku app as private?

I would like to deploy several internal services at heroku and make them only accessible between themselves. I would like to do it this way to hide the backend from the internet access and only allow a frontend app to be accessed by users from outside.
By default, practically everyone who can guess the correct heroku domain could access the backend and attack it directly.

Update:
To be more specific: I am looking for an altenative way besides Heroku private spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. What you should do if you need this functionality is to secure your web applications with a protocol like HTTP Basic Auth, or OAuth2 Client Credentials. Either of these will allow you to securely authenticate requests BETWEEN your Heroku apps without leaking data publicly.